# RMAN backups only get larger and don't delete

Tags: oracle, rman

I’m having some problems with my RMAN backups.  Sorry if this is a basic question but  I have little experience of RMAN backups.

The RMAN script and backup process was set up by the person who originally installed the DB.
It is supposed to do an incremental backup daily at 12:05 am and 12:05 pm and a full backup every three days.

The backups get consistently larger over time, often being much larger than my datafiles. Even with very little done ~100Mb is added each day (see table below).

If a full backup is being run every 3 days then why are the incremental backups being kept and things keep getting larger and larger overtime? Surely every 3 days the incremental backups should be reset and the backup folders reach a steady state size?

Some details below

Backup folder size and date

```
Date    Size
22-Jun  250Mb
23-Jun  161Mb
24-Jun  368Mb
25-Jun  450Mb
26-Jun  500Mb
27-Jun  1Gb
28-Jun  1.4Gb
29-Jun  1.3Gb
30-Jun  1.5Gb
01-Jul  1.62Gb
02-Jul  1.7Gb
03-Jul  1.8Gb
04-Jul  1.9Gb
05-Jul  2.3Gb
06-Jul  2.55Gb
07-Jul  2.64Gb
08-Jul  3.2Gb
```

There can be lots of row deletes and inserts on the database but overall the number of rows stays about then same.

If I do

```
SELECT * FROM V$RECOVERY_FILE_DEST
```

It shows

```
Name - /u02/fast_recovery_area  
Space limit 42949672960 
Space used 32024304640  
Space reclaimable 1786222080
Number_of_files 177
```

If I do a

```
export ORACLE_SID=CS2DB
rman target sys/sys
delete backup completed before 'sysdate -7';
```

It deletes all backups older than 7 days except the first one on 2014-06-22 (which was then deleted the next time the RMAN script below was run).

```
SELECT * FROM V$RECOVERY_FILE_DEST
```

After a delete sysdate-7 shows..

```
Space limit 42949672960 
Space used 23694853120  
Space reclaimable 1786222080
```

My rman backup script is

```
#!/bin/sh
. /home/oracle11/.bash_profile
CURR_DATE=`date +%u`
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/rman target / nocatalog log=/home/oracle11/script/log/rman_alo_$CURR_DATE.log << EOF
RUN {
allocate channel ch1 type disk;
RECOVER COPY OF DATABASE WITH TAG "fra_incr_backup_3d" UNTIL TIME 'SYSDATE - 3';
BACKUP INCREMENTAL LEVEL 1 FOR RECOVER OF COPY WITH TAG "fra_incr_backup_3d" DATABASE plus archivelog;
delete noprompt obsolete;
release channel ch1;
}
exit;
EOF
```

The RMAN retention policy is 7 days.

If a full backup is being run every 3 days then why are the incremental backups being kept and things keep getting larger and larger overtime? Surely every 3 days the incremental should reset?

Also why aren't backups being deleted every 7 days?

Comment: You have to understand the characteristics of FRA. Oracle will utilize almost all space in FRA and automatically delete (reclaimable) when space pressure is coming up. From my experience around 80% full. This link can be useful: https://uhesse.com/2011/09/22/the-recovery-area-why-it-is-recommended/

Answer (score 1):

you don't delete the archived log files and keep backing them up every time.

add something like

```
backup archivelog all not backed up 1 times;
delete noprompt archivelog all completed before 'sysdate -7';
```